# Converting Raw byte data to float[] and values needs to be between -1 and 1

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bitconverter

I don't if I am doing it right, but I am using this method to convert a byte array to float array as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056635/converting-raw-byte-data-to-float) :

```
public static float[] ConvertByteToFloat(byte[] array) {   
        float[] floatArr = new float[array.Length / 4];   
        for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++) {
              if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
                 Array.Reverse(array, i * 4, 4);
              }
              floatArr[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(array, i * 4);   
        }   
        return floatArr; 
}
```

*the input array is an array containing wave raw data (with no header)*

The problem is that i am getting (after conversion) values like :

> -9.66012E+24, 1963.15576, -5.11384777E-36, -1.19718621E-07

How can I convert this array to a float array and its **values should be between -1.0 and 1.0**?

Edit:

my input array starts like this :

```
byte[] {
    232,
    255,
    235,
    255,
    232,
    255,
    235,
    255,
    232,
    255,
    235,
    255,
    232,
    255,
    235,
    255,
...
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` and let's see what happens...

Comment: I am getting NaNs

Comment: The code seems to be correct (if we ignore the possible `IsLittleEndian` problem)... You could for example tell us some bytes of the sequence (around 16 bytes should be enough)... Are you sure they are 4 bytes floating point values and not 8 bytes doubles?

Comment: I've added a sample in my post

Comment: The `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` check makes only sense if the array of bytes was created on a big endian machine. If the bytes were created on the same machine reversing them is incorrect.

Comment: These bytes do not represent floats between -1 and +1. You need to know what they *do* represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [the implementation of `WriteSample()`](https://github.com/SjB/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveFileWriter.cs):

```
    public void WriteSample(float sample)
    {
        if (WaveFormat.BitsPerSample == 16)
        {
            writer.Write((Int16)(Int16.MaxValue * sample));
            dataChunkSize += 2;
        }
        ...
```

Note how that it converts a `float` to a 16-bit signed integer by multiplying it by `Int16.MaxValue`. That's because the internal data format is signed 16-bit integers between -Int16.MaxValue and +Int16.MaxValue.

This means that the values you're working with are `Int16` (aka `short`), and you need to convert them back to floats by dividing them by `Int16.MaxValue`.

For example, given your sample input:

```
byte[] bytes = { 232, 255, 235, 255, 232, 255, 235, 255, 232, 255, 235, 255, 232, 255, 235, 255 };

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 4; i += 4)
{
    float f = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i) / (float)Int16.MaxValue; 
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, it worked for me, I draw a spectrum and the values are between -1 and 1 and the spectrum is fine. You only need to change float f = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i) / (float)Int16.MaxValue;  with float f = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i/4) / (float)Int16.MaxValue;